# How to get Sybase replication definitions code?

Tags: replication, sybase, sap-ase, database-replication, sybase-rs

How to get the code of all replication definitions of a Sybase server?

If possible and since I'm new to this, give me a little explanation on them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use Replication Monitoring Services (RMS)
- Various stored procedures and shell scripts for reverse-engineering RepServer objects can be downloaded from http://repserver.codexchange.sybase.com (link 'repserver', folder Admin Tools/Scripts)
- PowerDesigner provides reverse-engineering but might require a special license

Comment: Unfortunately, since Sybase was bought by SAP, the codexchange.sybase.com website is gone.  

Also note, as of repserver 15.7.1 the RMS product is no longer included with the repserver distribution.   The documentation web pages say to download it from the "Sybase" website (which doesn't exist anymore, it just redirects to sap.com).   I tried a search the SAP Support Portal, but RMS wasn't found.

It sounds like RMS might be going away.

Answer (score 3):

Much of the information about your replication system can be found using the various help functions in the RSSD/ERSSD.  The specific commands will vary somewhat based on the kind of Replication you are using (Warm Standby, Function String, Table, Procedure, mixed).

[**rs_helpdb**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/X34997.htm) *[ dataserver, database ]*:  Shows all databases known by the RSSD.  If you specify dataserver/datbase, it will only show information for that connection. Output lists Server/Database, rep dbid, primary RS, errorclass, repserver errorclass, function class and status.

**[rs_helprepdb](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/refman299.htm)**:  Shows replicate databases that have subscriptions to primary data in the current RS, or shows the specified DS/DB.

Other commands that will help:

**[rs_helprep](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/X38984.htm)** Displays information about replication definitions

**[rs_helpsub](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/X36706.htm)** Displays information about subscriptions

**[rs_helpreptable](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/refman304.htm)**  Displays information about replication definitions created against a primary table.

**[rs_helppub](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/X17645.htm)**  Displays information about publications.

**[rs_helppubsub](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/X19912.htm)**  Displays information about publication subscriptions and article subscriptions.

**[rs_helpdbrep](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/CHDCFBJJ.htm)**  Displays information about database replication definitions associated with the current Replication Server

**[rs_helpdbsub](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1550/html/refman/CHDGBEHD.htm)**  Displays information about database subscriptions associated with the replicate data server.

These commands all pull information from the tables in the RSSD, so you can also poke around the RSSD to find the information you are looking for.  Here is the [RS table diagram](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc70003.1550/pdf/rs155pst.pdf?noframes=true) to help.

Also, if you are going to do any regular replication work, I highly recommend Rob Verschoors *The Complete Sybase Replication Server Quick Reference Guide* ([www.sypron.nl](http://www.sypron.nl)), as it has >90% of what you need to create and manage a Sybase rep environment.